# IEEEtran bibliography style doesn't work

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran, ieee-style, cite-package

I'm using IEEEtran bibliography style, but for some reason it isn't working.

My paper.tex file includes the most recent version of IEEEtran files,
as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}
```

The command I'm using to build is:

```
bibtex paper
latex paper
latex paper
```

The output I get is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \end{thebibliography}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: You need to latex _before_ bibtex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your help, but I already did that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please make a complete, small, document that shows the problem and bib file and edit them in to your answer.